# Getting raster tiles that overlap

Tags: postgis, raster

I'm trying to create a multiband raster from several component rasters, which have the same alignment. The first step is to identify which tiles completely overlap (i.e., have the same extent and upper left coordinates).

From the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html), it would seem that `r1.rast=r2.rast` would be a quick way to identify these tiles, i.e. are the bounding boxes the same.

But the `=` operator is identifying tiles in completely different parts of the world. Moreover, the `~=` operator (which should be the same as `=` but with lower precision) is returning `False`.

```
SELECT r1.rast~=r2.rast, r1.rast=r2.rast 
FROM raster1 AS r1, raster2 AS r2
WHERE g1.rid=66585 AND g2.rid=170411
```

returns `False, True` for the row in question. How is that possible?